# black outside area in material dialog box

Tags: angular, angular10

"black background did not show in my project , anyone help me? i didn't add additional thing to my dialog or my project"

which i want it
[image]

this is my project
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this by adding this to CSS

```
.backdropBackground {
  filter: blur(20px);
  background-color: gray;
  opacity: 0.7 !important;
}
```

Comment: thaks for answer, but it isnt work for me